# Distributing Internet equally among several users

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, router

I have a very basic setup which follow the following diagram -

[ISP] === [Linux Home Router] ==== [Client1 .. n]

Internet sharing is working without any problem. But the main issue is that if any client starts download other client experience serious network slow down.

So I want to distribute the internet bandwidth among the clients equally which guarantees a minimum of 160Kb upto 1Mbit.

I tried to change the queue in the iptables but I think I am missing something there as it does not work.

Comment: Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.

Comment: "*So I want to distribute the internet bandwidth among the clients equally which guarantees a minimum of 160Kb upto 1Mbit.*" That assumes that what needs to be shared is bandwidth. But people care an awful lot about latency too. A "perfectly fair" distribution of bandwidth might be perfectly fair to the people using torrenting downloaders, but a person trying to play games will be awfully unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need traffic control instead of IPTables rules. There is a manual for the 'tc' program:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/

And a simple tutorial for its usage:

http://chsoft.biz/lartc/tc_tutorial.html

Following these, you can create a simple rule to distribute the traffic equally.